# What does PCIe Gen3x4 means

Tags: pci-express

I've performed some google search but could not found any answer to this term: PCIe Gen3x4. Could someone help me?

Does that means it uses PCIe 3.0 with 4 lanes?

Answer (score 8):

Generally, when referring to PCI Express specifications, the "x" in the term signifies the number of lanes.

In your example, PCIe Gen3x4 should be interpreted as PCI Express, Generation 3, using 4 lanes. It's probably worth noting that the "x4" can refer to not just the number of lanes that the device will connect with, but also the physical size of the PCIe slot (see [this example](https://www.dummies.com/wp-content/uploads/291549.image0.jpg)).

Additionally, not all slots that are a certain size will always carry the number of data lanes generally associated with that slot size. For example, motherboards will sometimes carry x16 sized slots that only carry 8 data lanes.